# Is there a way to transform a pentadiagonal matrix into a tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I have been working with the Schrödinger equation in spheroidal coordinates. The difference equation we get using Frobenius's method or usual series method results in a pentadiagonal matrix, if we don't use some tricks. Does anyone know some paper that helps?

Comment: Why is tridiagonal matrix desirable? What kind of problem are you solving? Is it a system of linear equations or an eigenvalue problem?

Comment: @MatheusEliasPereira You can even transform it into a diagonal matrix by using Gaussian elimination...

Comment: @uranix it is an eigenvalue problem, which i want to solve exactly. The problem is that upon using a Frobenius's usual solution, we get a 5 term difference equation. If it were 3 term, all good, there are continued fraction methods, so that's why it's desirable.

Comment: Is your matrix symmetric? In that case reduction to Hessenberg form will make it tridiagonal. See [Numerical recipes](https://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/numerical_recipes.pdf) p. 578, for example. I've never heard about continued fraction methods for eigenproblems with tridiagonal matrices, could you please share some paper about it?

Comment: @uranix sure, there is this one https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/two-centre-problem-in-wave-mechanics/1D975E6C72A66FAA0F3AE4B8892A34A9 , by Baber and Hassé. I did my undergrad monograph based on this one. There are more, such as books like Spheroidal Wave Functions, by Flammer, as old as this one. But i think no, the matrix is not symmetric. I was thinking that there must be a way to make a generalized pentadiagonal matrix to become a tridiagonal symmetric one.